# What points can fit into a regular n-gon

Tags: geometry

I have an optimization problem which requires that, for the vertices of the regular $n$-gon, $p_{1:n}$ stored as columns of a matrix $P$, $Px$ must be inside the bounded region of the $n$-gon.

For example, if $n=3$, then I have three vertices in $\mathbb{R}^2$ which form an equilateral triangle, and I want to know what set of points lie inside that triangle in terms of its vertices.

I am trying to write out these constraints more formally.

I considered writing that $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i = 1$, but I don't think these conditions work. At least, I wouldn't even know how to prove it.

How can I write the constraints in terms of $P$ and $x$ such that $Px$ is in the bounded region of the regular $n$-gon?

Comment: When you say in the area, do you mean in the bounded region?  If so, then $\sum_{i=1}^nx_i=1$ with $x_i\geq 0$ will give a convex combination of the vertices.

Comment: @MichaelBurr Yes

Comment: @MichaelBurr Wow, that was fast. Thank you!

Comment: @MichaelBurr Follow-up here if you're interested: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2212032/what-algorithm-technique-solves-this-non-linear-constrained-optimization-problem