# How to find an initial point for this convex optimization problem?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

This is sort of a followup to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2212032/how-to-solve-this-nonlinear-constrained-optimization-problem), but with nonlinear constraints instead of a nonlinear objective function.
$$
\begin{align*}
  \text{Find } x \text{ that maximizes } & (Ax)^{\top} y \\
  \text{Subject to } & ||Ax|| = 1 \\
    & x_i \geq 0 \; \forall \: i \in \{1\dots n\} \\
  \text{Where } & A \in \mathbb{R}^{d \, \times \, n} \\
    & x \in \mathbb{R}^n \\
    & y \in \mathbb{R}^d \\
    & A_{i,j} \geq 0 \, \forall \, i \in \{1\dots d\}, j \in \{1\dots n\} \\
    & y_i \geq 0 \, \forall \, i \in \{1\dots d\} \\
    & ||y|| = 1 \\
    & ||a_i|| = 1 \, \forall \text{ column vectors } a_i \text{ in } A
\end{align*}
$$

I am using a software package which solves convex nonlinear optimization. However, I need a starting point $x^0$ that satisfies the constraints.

So, my problem is: find a vector $x^0$ such that $||Ax||=1$ and $x_i \geq 0 \, \forall i$.

Comment: Are you using the $2$-norm?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo yes

Comment: Your goal is to find a point that satisfies the constraints?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Yeah, but I don't know what I was thinking when I made this question because I could just take any nonnegative vector $x$, then let $x_0=x/||Ax||$.